# How to write XPath under tag: strong

Tags: xpath

I want to red text under strong tag I have written XPath like:

```
//section[2]/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/text()[1]
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="listing-info">
    <h4>Listing Information</h4>
    <strong style="">Load #:</strong> 238635<br>
    <strong>Date Listed:</strong> 5/11/17 2:12PM<br>
    <strong>Ready to Load:</strong> 5/12/17 8:00AM<br>
    <br>
    <strong>Stock #:</strong> Old unit #17<br>
    <strong>Serial #:</strong> 2FZAASDC35AU00313<br>
    <strong>PO #:</strong> <br>
    <strong>Cargo Value:</strong> <br>
    <strong>Year:</strong> 2017<br>
    <br>
    <strong>Shipper's Completed Jobs:</strong> (0)<br>
    <br>
</div>
```

I want to locate the values of the `strong` elements:

```
238635, 5/11/17 2:12PM, 5/12/17 8:00AM
```

I tried but was unable to read the text value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you expect to query is actually placed **not "under"** `strong` tag, **but "next to"** `strong` tag. There is the `text nodes` that you should take. Hence you should take all the `text nodes` having string as **preceding sibling** and filter out the nodes filled with white-spaces.

Use this xpath:

```
//div[@class='listing-info']/text()[preceding-sibling::strong][normalize-space()!='']
```

Tested in https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Note that your xml is not well-formed so in that online tester you should make your BR tags closed.

```
<div class="listing-info">
    <h4>Listing Information</h4>
    <strong style="">Load #:</strong> 238635<br/>
    <strong>Date Listed:</strong> 5/11/17 2:12PM<br/>
    <strong>Ready to Load:</strong> 5/12/17 8:00AM<br/>
    <br/>
    <strong>Stock #:</strong> Old unit #17<br/>
    <strong>Serial #:</strong> 2FZAASDC35AU00313<br/>
    <strong>PO #:</strong> <br/>
    <strong>Cargo Value:</strong> <br/>
    <strong>Year:</strong> 2017<br/>
    <br/>
    <strong>Shipper's Completed Jobs:</strong> (0)<br/>
    <br/>
</div>
```

The output is:

```
Text=' 238635'
Text=' 5/11/17 2:12PM'
Text=' 5/12/17 8:00AM'
Text=' Old unit #17'
Text=' 2FZAASDC35AU00313'
Text=' 2017'
Text=' (0)'
```

**UPD:**
According to comment provided, it seems that original html snippet didn't represent the actual state. Here is the test on original source:

**xPath:**

```
//div[@class='equipment_item']//text()[preceding-sibling::strong][normalize-space()!='']
```

**Result:**

[image]

In case you need some particular item, use approach like this:

```
//div[@class='equipment_item']//text()[preceding-sibling::strong[text()='Load #:']][1]
```